# API OMC cTrader with FIX44

Tags: python-3.x, api, networking, fix-protocol, algorithmic-trading

I have some issues with connecting ctrader with FIX44 using PyFIX.

When I add the address and a port to my client, it has an error. The code:  https://github.com/wannabegeek/PyFIX

My code:

```
class Client(FIXEngine):
    def __init__(self):
        FIXEngine.__init__(self, "h50.p.ctrader.com")
        self.clOrdID = 0
        self.msgGenerator = None

        # create a FIX Client using the FIX 4.4 standard
        self.client = FIXClient(self, "pyfix.FIX44", "TARGET", "SENDER")

        # we register some listeners since we want to know when the connection goes up or down
        self.client.addConnectionListener(self.onConnect, ConnectionState.CONNECTED)
        self.client.addConnectionListener(self.onDisconnect, ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)

        # start our event listener indefinitely
        self.client.start('178.62.43.199', int("5211"))

        while True:
            self.eventManager.waitForEventWithTimeout(10.0)

        # some clean up before we shut down
        self.client.removeConnectionListener(self.onConnect, ConnectionState.CONNECTED)
        self.client.removeConnectionListener(self.onConnect, ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED)
```

That's the error:

```
2017-09-23 10:56:23,631 Client disconnected
2017-09-23 10:56:23,631 ('178.62.43.199', 5211) has disconnected
2017-09-23 10:56:23,631 Attempting Connection to 178.62.43.199:5211
2017-09-23 10:56:23,740 Connected to ('178.62.43.199', 5211)
2017-09-23 10:56:23,868 Established connection to ('178.62.43.199', 5211)
2017-09-23 10:56:23,869 Connection has been closed [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
2017-09-23 10:56:23,869 Client disconnected
2017-09-23 10:56:23,869 ('178.62.43.199', 5211) has disconnected
2017-09-23 10:56:23,869 Attempting Connection to 178.62.43.199:5211
2017-09-23 10:56:23,980 Connected to ('178.62.43.199', 5211)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyfix/connection.py", line 150, in handle_read
    msg = self.sock.recv(8192)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I'm from Egypt, and the client is from New Zealand, is it an issue because of the IPs of Egypt?

Answer (score 0):

### No, most probably it is not rejected due to Egypt IP address

The exact reasons are hard to state from a limited amount of posted details.

Nevertheless, most of the FIX Protocol-based API service providers do not allow your code to connect naked across the global internet.

There are typically ssh-application-gateway encrypted connectivity and user-access authorisation first, so that the actual trading-transactions and quote-stream events both flow across an encrypted ssh-tunnel and all the content remains protected from unauthorised { passive | active }-activity or misuse.

Reconcile your access credentials, encryption details and the proper L3+ connectivity details with your FIX Protocol-based API service provider, so as to configure both your local-end of the access-plane and the XTO/QUOTE-plane for the trading-stream and the quote-stream interfaces in such a manner to exactly meet the service provider's documentation.

For natural reasons, there is no other way forwards.